# Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error? Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Here is what I have, taken right off of PHPs site for stored procedures

```
$stmt = db::getInstance();
$stmt->prepare("CALL delete(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(2122, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
$stmt->execute();
print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `bindParam()` method is inside the [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class, not the PDO class.  The statement is the **result** of the `prepare()` method.

```
$foo = db::getInstance();
$stmt = $foo->prepare("CALL delete(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(2122, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
$stmt->execute();
print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

The [bindParam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) function is a method of a `PDOStatement` object, not a PDO object.  `$stmt` is an object of class `PDO`.  You'll have to use the `PDOStatement` from your `prepare()` call instead.

```
$pdo = db::getInstance();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("your query");
$stmt->bindParam(2122, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = db::getInstance(); 
$query = $stmt->prepare("CALL delete(?)"); 
$query->bindParam(2122, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
$query->execute();
```

You need to be calling PDOStatment::bindParam. The prepare method returns the PDOStatment Object. [The PHP PDO/PDOStatment manuals should help.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Hi Munch. What is PDOStatement

Comment: It's the current instance of the Prepared Statement that you're working with. PDO::prepare will prepare the statement for you and return the PDOStatment, which you can them manipulate (bindParam, execute, etc). The link in my answer will show you all the methods.