# How to fix call to undefined function prepare() in PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo, undefined

**QUESTION:** Why am I getting `Call to undefined function prepare()`  error ?
How can I fix it?

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059258/call-to-undefined-method-pdobindparam) is similar to my question, but I don't know how to apply the answer to my case.

```
$myNull = null;
$table="test_results";  
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (instance, uid, testid, quizstart, quizend, score)
        VALUES (
                :instance, 
                :uid,
                :testid, 
                :quizstart,
                :quizend,
                :score)";

try {
    /*** connect to DB ***/  
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


    $stmt = $dbh>prepare($sql); //  **************ERROR HERE****************

    $stmt->bindParam(':instance', $myNull, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':testid', $tid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':quizstart', $quizstart,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':quizend', $quizend,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':score', $score,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

     /*** display the id of the last INSERT ***/
    $lastInsertValue=$dbh->lastInsertId();

    $stmt->closeCursor();

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used greater than operator instead of arrow (`->`)

```
$dbh>prepare($sql); //WRONG
$dbh->prepare($sql); // CORRECT
```

Comment: I can't believe how much time I've wasted on such a simple mistake. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `-`. Try this

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```