# PDO selecting rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I just started learning PDO (and to be honest, I'm not fairly sure what I'm doing) and I want my code to get the number of rows that have the username that the user inputted, so that I would be able to check if the username already exists. This is what I have so far.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user_check = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$dbh->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user_row_count = $user_check->rowCount();
echo $user_row_count;
```

However this gives me an error that says  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam() in /var/www/register.php on line 41

Comment: You need to call `bindParam` on your query (`$user_check`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059258/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minor niggles:

1. [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) actually executes the SQL provided as its argument; to use SQL that includes parameter placeholders, you must first *prepare* the query and then *execute* it.
2. The *result* of a call to [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is a [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, which supports the [`bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method.
3. One must *execute* a statement before one can obtain the number of rows that it returns.

Therefore:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user_check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$user_check->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user_check->execute();
$user_row_count = $user_check->rowCount();
echo $user_row_count;
```