# PDO SELECT JOIN QUERY

Tags: php

I tested the code below it works fine on phpmyadmin

```
SELECT registered_user_tbl.username, follow.follower_id FROM registered_user_tbl
  INNER JOIN follow
  ON follow.follower_id= 5 and registered_user_tbl.user_id= 5
```

I now want to implement the array version on my pdo project but it is not working kindly check and review query below

```
$this->db->select("SELECT registered_user_tbl.username, follow.follower_id FROM registered_user_tbl
    INNER JOIN follow
    ON follow.follower_id= :fid and registered_user_tbl.user_id= :fid",
    (":fid" =>$user));
```

Comment: Please specify "is not working" and provide any error messages that appear in the html page or the server log.

Comment: What is `$this->db->select` **not standard PHP code** so you had better show that as well

Comment: Did you mean to pass an array on that command if so maybe try `[":fid" =>$user]`

Comment: You cannot reuse bound parameters in most setups. You'll need to rename one of them.

Comment: the first one worked but  the second one is returning null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO selecting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470843/pdo-selecting-rows)

Comment: there is no select() method in PDO

Comment: aynber can please talk more about what you meant by "reuse bound parameters"

Comment: @sambayour I identified that issue in my answer

Comment: @riggsfolly that is the way the MVC framework am using has being setup

Comment: Well show us that code in the `->select()` method of your MVC Framework

Comment: Have you set PDO up to throw Exceptions? Are you getting any? If not are you checking for errors in the _Old Fashioned Way_

Comment: @sambayour Can you please specify the exact error and status you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to your `select()` method should probably be an array so the round brackets are incorrect, for your data parameters.

And you cannot reuse `:fid` twice in the parameter substitution.

So try this

```
$this->db->select(
        "SELECT registered_user_tbl.username, follow.follower_id 
        FROM registered_user_tbl
            INNER JOIN follow ON follow.follower_id= :fid1 
                and registered_user_tbl.user_id= :fid2",
        [":fid1" =>$user, ":fid2" =>$user]
        );
```

Comment: Then show us your `->select()` method code, or maybe you are trying to use a PDO method that does not exist ? There is no vanilla `PDO::select()` method